# Is there a way to get Sum of values from a range based on a range criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a pivot table with two columns; key and value. The pivot table can have one or more rows.

I need to get the sum of the values of one or more keys based on a criteria. The criteria could be one or more keys spread in a range (Labelled "Lookup example 1" in the screenshot) or on one cell with one or more keys that are delimited by a comma or any unique character (Labelled "Lookup example 2" in the screenshot). The criteria can have one or more keys.

Is it possible to make a formula in excel that would get the sum using only one cell?

Here is a visual example:

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,D2:D3))`

Comment: Another alternative way : `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(A:A,D2:D3,0)),B:B)`

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Scott Craner in the comments to my question
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,D2:D3))